# manageObjectContext failure

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Simple app starts with a table view in a navigation controller with an add button.
My problem is here:

```
func saveName(name: String) {
    //1
    let appDelegate =
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
```

I have issue:

> 'AppDelegate' does not have a member named 'managedObjectContext'

Thanks.

Comment: Well what does your app delegate include?

Comment: The error message is quite clear on what the problem is. Your app delegate does not have a managed object context.